MySQL functional index with IS NULL
I have a large table in MySQL with a slow query partly due to a condition like WHERE sent_at IS NULL. sent_at is a nullable datetime column but here we only want to check if it's null so a standard index across all values would be wasteful.
I've discovered that creating a functional index with ISNULL() or IS NULL works but it is never used for queries.
E.g.
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX index_users_sent_at_is_null ((ISNULL(sent_at)));

Followed by the query:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE (sent_at IS NULL);

Will have a (JSON) EXPLAIN output with access_type: "ALL" and no possible or selected keys listed.
Doing the equivalent for YEAR(sent_at) works as expected by using the relevant functional index, so there is something special about IS NULL even though the virtual hidden column the functional index produces correctly contains 0 or 1.
Is there an elegant way to make this work?

Have you checked the cardinality of the index? Does it help if you change the index expression to sent_at IS NULL (ideally the two forms should be equivalent, but it's MySQL we're talking about).

This index can have two possible values: true or false. The selectivity of such index is probably too low for mysql to consider it.

@Shadow I'd expect explain to show it as a possible key still.

it does not seem possible to index is null without a generated column (or the workaround bill suggests): https://dbfiddle.uk/060bclIz

I tested your example index with MySQL 8.0.37 on my local Macbook. I can reproduce the problem you describe:
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE (sent_at IS NULL)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where

This is related to https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99775, where a functional index is not used when you use the expression in your WHERE clause without comparing the result to a specific value. This bug was verified in 2020, but has not been fixed yet (as of June 2024).
As a workaround, you can compare the expression to a specific constant value, and then the query can use the index:
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE (sent_at IS NULL) = 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_users_sent_at_is_null
          key: index_users_sent_at_is_null
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL

You may think that logically, these queries are the same, and you shouldn't have to use the workaround to engage the optimization. Yes, I agree. That's why this is a bug.

The source of this bug is the absence of the BOOLEAN datatype in MySQL. The datatype of the (sent_at IS NULL) expression is not non-existent BOOLEAN but INTEGER (i.e. 4-byte numeric). We can see this by investigating the index part of the table body file, it stores 80 00 00 00 for TRUE and 00 00 00 00 for FALSE. So formally  the server needs to apply the function to the expression value which is stored in the index and detect does the value is not FALSE/NULL. Rather than immediate compare with some definite value.
